# Passing data from Laravel Blade to Vue component

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, laravel-blade

I'm passing data from my Laravel Blade to my Vue component. The question can actually apply to any variable passed on from my blade template file to a Vue component.

For this example, I am passing a translation variable. I know there are translation packages to translate the language files to a json format, and from there import it to my component - I have that, and it is working. My question is rather about passing a variable from blade to Vue.

Everything I have, is working - I just want to know what the "correct way" would be.

So in my blade file I have;

```
<my-component :myvariable="'{{ trans('app.test_translation') }}'"></my-component>
```

In my component I have

```
props: {
    myvariable: String,
},
```

And in my component template I have an icon

```
<i class="fa fa-info-circle" :title="myvariable"></i>
```

The result is that if I hover over the icon, I get the expected output.

Would this be the correct way to achieve what I want to achieve?

An alternative method which I can apply is to define the variable in my controller, as an example

```
$myvariable = trans('app.test_translation');
```

Then pass the variable to my blade file

```
compact('myvariable')
```

And from my blade file to my Vue component

```
<my-component :myvariable="'{{ $myvariable }}'"></my-component>
```

I want to refrain from doing verbose stuff and I want refrain from doing stuff that "just works" - I am trying to do the "correct" way.

Or is there another method or suggestion?

Or should I stick to making use of the Lang.js pack, by defining the Lang variable and importing the messages (translations) into every component as such?

```
window.Lang = require('lang.js');
const Lang = new window.Lang({
    messages
});
import messages from '../vue-translations.js';
```

I have defined the latter in my app.js file - but evertime I want to make use of one or more translations in a Vue component, I have to import all the translations as in the last example above.

I would appreciate your input!

Thanx.

Comment: What I worry about, is that if,for example, I make use of variables and I pass my translation variables from either a controller or the blade file, then I my component string will get too long and messy like for example, <component :var1="var1" :var2="var3" :var1="var1"></component> - would it be better or the "right way" just to simply import the translation file to every component?

Comment: Another thought; Lets say I have 3 input boxes, each with a placeholder. Such as, `placeholder="This is one placeholder"`

Now if I import my translations to my component, I have to define each placeholder in my "data" inside the script of my component, to be able to use it in my component template.

Comment: As an example, if I make use of the imported translations, I would have to declare `data { placeholder1: 'this is placeholder one', }` then inside my first input field, in my component template `:placeholder="placeholder1"` - because I can not refer to the translation directly, like for example, `placeholder="{{ 'placeholder1' | trans }}"` - or is there a way that I can say `<input type="text" placeholder="my translation here">`

Comment: http://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/ and https://github.com/martinlindhe/laravel-vue-i18n-generator might be something to look at.